# AD9850 comparator problem. How to calculate is frequency?

Tags: signal, comparator, dds, signal-processing

I want to convert a sine wave produced from [AD9850](http://www.analog.com/static/imported-files/data_sheets/AD9850.pdf) (opens *.pdf) into square wave with its inbuilt comparator. AD9850 has a fast comparator with 3ns rise/fall time and propagation delay= 5.5ns.

without accounting the propagation delay , it should work up to 1/(2x3ns)= 83MHz. If I add propagation delay, it will be 1/(2x3ns + 5.5ns)= 43.48 MHz. if I account the same time for settling and flat part of the square wave and some error tolerance, it should at least tolerate around 20MHz.

But it is not what really happens. the output wave is not a square wave higher than 5MHz ( it is more like a noise). The input signal of the comparator is well low pass filtered and is a clean sine wave with around 2v pk-pk.

Is there anything wrong in my calculations?

***EDITION:*** I am using [this module](http://elecfreaks.com/store/download/datasheet/breakout/DDS/Schematic.pdf) with a reliable ground plane:

Comment: Is your o-scope fast enough? I'd say 3ns rise, 3ns fall and 6ns top and bottom should give you a reasonable 80MHz signal.

Comment: A schematic indicating what you have implemented and how you are measuring this would be helpful.

Comment: @Andyaka yes it is a 200MHz one with good quality.

Comment: @Aug - does the onboard comparator require localized de-coupling capacitors? Are there any decoupling capacitors you have forgotten about. What about the signal size going into the comparator - bigger the better (within the power rails of course)!

Comment: Spec indicates ground plane , decoupling cap close to 5V and ground and 15pF load.  Use barrel of probe & tip with sleeve & gnd clip removed between Qout and Gnd with 10x calibrated probe.

Comment: @rawbrawb a link to my module schematic added. Thanks!

Comment: @Andyaka As you said, I tried the commercial module instead of my own design, but of no avail yet! . The link to the module added as an edition.

Comment: @user30080 It seems a good suggestion but actually I got confused between these many "&"s !. You mean I don't use sleeve clip connected to the ground or something?

Comment: And ... **HOW** are you using the module?

Comment: @rawbrawb   I simply connect IOUT to VIN. It works fine up to 2-5 MHz and duty cycle can be adjusted with module's inbuilt pot. All module GND connections are well decoupled with multiple 100 nF ceramic capacitors.

Comment: OP Amp cannot drive this small capacative load without instability. Use a 10:1 probe with 15pF load max if you want to  follow specs. The Pull down resistor adds margin, the feedback resistors being too low, removes margin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there's a bit of circuitry between the output of the dac and the input of the comparator on that board.  Connect a four channel scope to the outputs and inputs directly on the chip and view the waveforms present.  I suspect you'll find your answer.

You'll notice in the datasheet that the comparator jitter graph is performed at 40MHz, so it's capable of running at that speed.  Chances are good you have low signal quality at VINP, an improperly set VINN threshold, or both. As the frequency goes up, the circuit impedance reduces the signal power, and it's having a hard time seeing it.